# Separability of Laplace Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

In the context of working in spherical coordinates, we can generally find solutions to the Laplace equation by assuming they separate into radial and angular components (spherical harmonics). However there could also be solutions that obviously don’t separate (case in point the sum of two different separable solutions).

However, my question is: can ANY solution be represented as an infinite sum of these solutions? For example, in my physics textbook, it is assumed that if we assume azimuthal symmetry (m = 0) and we know what the potential is along the Z axis, then we can know the potential everywhere else in space. But this rests upon the fact that any solution in some volume D can always be represented by an infinite series of these separable solutions.

Is this true, and is this difficult to prove? Basically I’m asking because we always assume that this sum is the “general” solution, but how do we know that’s true? How do we know there’s not possibly other solutions that could be added?

Comment: 'We always assume that this sum is the "general" solution, but how do we know that's true?'. It's only the general solution to Laplaces equation _given some associated boundary data_. Once you have the boundary data, you can [show uniqueness the same way we do with all of the standard PDE problems.](http://teacher.pas.rochester.edu/PHY217/LectureNotes/Chapter3/LectureNotesChapter3.html).

Comment: Yes I understand the laplace equation can be shown to be unique under certain boundary conditions (Dirlichet, Neumann etc. etc.) but in Jackson Electrodynamics he basically leaves the general solution in spherical coordinates in terms of un fixed constants. Then he basically says, if we assume Azimuthal symmetry and we know the potential along the Z-Axis, since the expansion is true for any solution, then the solution we get is unique. We never explicitly enforce boundary conditions besides assuming azimuthal symmetry and a known potential along the axis.

Comment: For example in that same link you sent, look at the section about "3.3.2. Separation of variables: spherical coordinates". There they also provide the same "General" solution. But how do we know, for a fact, this represents ALL possible solutions? We have enforced no boundary conditions.

Comment: Any response @mattos ?